# memory allocation for php

Tags: php, yii

I have PHP Version 7.2.9 on a Mac running OSX 10.13.6.  If I load phpinfo(), I see in safari the memory_limit = 256M.  However when I look in php.ini (/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini) the memory_limit = 128M.  What is the cause of this discrepancy - obviously the limit is set somewhere else, but where?  I need to increase the memory limit

Comment: Can you check how many PHP version has been setup in your server? May be you configure more than one like PHP5, PHP7 and you are checking in unset php version .ini file

Comment: Both php5 & php 7 are present. Both are associated with a php.ini file.  The ini files are identical - if you change one the change is reflected in the other.  I have also copied the php.ini file to /etc and done a restart.  But this still does not cause the memory limit to change.

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you are have a several configurtions (may be you are upgrade php5 to php7) So you are must to find a REAL configuration file of php.

Try

$> php --ini

So you find directory where are config files. Remember Web-config is an apache directory.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs in two environments.

### 1. CLI

You have the command line instance, which in your case is running version 5

> /etc/php/X/cli/php.ini

### 2. Webserver

You have the instance tied to your webserver. You can find in:

> /etc/php/X/apache2/php.ini

Changing the setting on any of them only affect that instance. The `X` stands for the version, so if you go to `/etc/php/` you should see what's available to you.

**Note:** in your case, `/etc/php/` should be switched to `/usr/local/php/`

Comment: running php --ini gives the location of the only php.ini file as /etc/php.ini.  the memory limit in this file does not correspond to that displayed by running phpinfo().  The version of php is 7.2.9.

Comment: `php --ini` is returning the cli version, while `phpinfo()` is returning the web server version

Comment: I have found the following: /etc/php.ini and /usr/local/php5-7.2.9-20180821-074958/lib/php.ini.  In /etc/php.ini I have remarked out the memory_limit setting and in /etc/php.ini and /usr/local/php5-7.2.9-20180821-074958/lib/php.in I have set the memory_limit = 600M (i.e. just and arbitrary value.  After stopping start the apache server and having reboot the laptop, phpinfo() returns the memory_limit = 256M.  Puzzled and confused.